# How to use enum outside of nesting class

Tags: swift, enums

In my app I'm using a class called `BaseNavigator`. It looks like this:

```
class BaseNavigator {
    enum Destination {

    }

    weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?

    func navigate(to destination: Destination, completion:((Bool) -> ())? = nil) {
        let viewController = makeViewController(for: destination)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

        completion?(true)
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to extend this class, so that I could, for example, create a `PreferencesNavigator`.

```
class PreferencesNavigator: BaseNavigator {
    enum Destination {
        case general
        case about
    }
}
```

This would allow me to use it like this:

```
let navigator = PreferencesNavigator()
navigator.navigate(to: .general)
```

However, when I try to compile this, Xcode starts complaining about `Destination` being ambiguous. How can I fix this?

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile, since `PreferencesNavigator` doesn't have a method called `navigate`. Are you sure you didn't mean to inherit from `BaseNavigator` instead of `NSObject`? Moreover, you shouldn't inherit from `NSObject` unless you have a good reason to do so, Swift is not Objective-C, classes don't need to inherit from any base class.

Comment: how would the `PreferencesNavigator` be an _extension_ of `BaseNavigator`?

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to inherit from `BaseNavigator`.

Comment: What i think @holex is saying is that you cannot call it inheritance if you do not inherit all the properties as it is. You cannot add more values to an enum. So you would have to create a new enum which means you would have to create another method to handle it. At this point, it is barely a subclass of the base navigator.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. And that would of course defeat the point of doing all of this, which was to prevent copying/pasting code in all these navigators.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer (IMO) is that you can't do this without making that enum private which I suspect will break your approach. You can read some more on extensions [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html).

I don't know the problem you are trying to solve but for my initial impressions I would propose that you do this via a protocol.

```
protocol BaseNavigator {
    func getDestination()
}
```

then so long as you have a class that conforms to that protocol you can call that method which you can adjust the return type in your protocol definition if needed.

Answer (score -2):

You are doing wrong as you don't have `navigate(to:` in `PreferencesNavigator` class so please do it:

Write Enum outside of `PreferencesNavigator`:

```
enum Destination {
   case general
   case about
}
```

and inherit BaseNavigator like this

```
class PreferencesNavigator: BaseNavigator {

}
```

Then your code will work

Comment: But then I couldn't have it contain different cases, based on which navigator it's implemented in, right?

Comment: @user4992124: I have updated my answer, please check